# Excel. How to count the number of repetitive cells?

Tags: excel

I need to write filter data in the Excel. How to count the number of repetitive cells?

Example
I have data in the column

```
    0
    0
    1
    0
    1
    1
    0
    1
    1
    1
    0
    1
    1
    1
    1
```

Output

```
Count 1 = 10
Count 1;1 = 4
Count 1;1;1 = 2 
Count 1;1;1;1 = 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Were you looking to use vba to achieve the result?

Comment: I need formula like = SUM()  =COUNTIF e. t..c.  I dont't use vba, because this file is created from the outside.

Comment: Can you put a concatenation of the values in the target column in 1 cell (ex `001011011101111`)? If so this is fairly straightforward

Comment: if it can be done using the formulas I can do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your values in A1:A15 and your choice for the number of consecutive 1s to be considered, e.g. 3, in B1, this **array formula**** in C1:

`=SUM(INT(FREQUENCY(IF(A$1:A$15=1,ROW(A$1:A$15)),IF(A$1:A$15=0,ROW(A$1:A$15)))/B1))`

Copy down to give similar results for variations on the number of consecutive 1s to be considered in B2, B3, etc.

As an example of how this operates, using the original data as given and with B1=2, we can see that the formula will become:

`=SUM(INT(FREQUENCY({FALSE;FALSE;3;FALSE;5;6;FALSE;8;9;10;FALSE;12;13;14;15},{1;2;FALSE;4;FALSE;FALSE;7;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;11;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE})/B1))`

The reason for the choice of IF statements for the *data_array* and *bins_array* should now be clear, the set of elements within each being the complement of the other.

As such, when we pass these arrays to FREQUENCY, we obtain an output consisting of the number of 1s within each grouping, the above resolving to:

`=SUM(INT({0;0;1;2;3;4}/B1))`

And the rest is reasonably straightforward.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Very nice use of `FREQUENCY` and the two `IF`s to split the data into groups and `INT` to avoid double counting.  Any way you can add a quick blurb about how it is using `FREQUENCY` to do the counting within those two groups?

Comment: I hope I don't have problem to write that formula from C# and it calculate after without hold CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: @Byron Thanks. And sure - will add something now.

Comment: Explanation is great.  Might not be obvious otherwise why you flipped the conditions since counting unique values uses the same range.  @askeet, look into `FormulaArray` as the programmatic way to enter an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Concatenate all of the values in the cells into one cell as a string (for this example I will assume that your data is in column A and the concatenation is in cell B1).
1(a)  In cell B1, enter the formula `=CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3,...,A_)`. This is very long winded if there is more than a handful of cells.
1(b)  Alternatively, a quick Google search yielded [**this**](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/) article which gives a fairly quick (but manual) way to concatenate a large range of values.

Step 2: Count the occurrences of a smaller string within the concatenation above.
2.1  Place the string that you want to search for in a cell (for this example I will assume cell C1)
2.2 In cell D1, enter the formula `=(LEN($B$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1,C1,"")))/LEN(C1)`. This works by searching a string and replacing each occurrence of a target string (C1) with a blank ("") and measuring the difference in length.
2.3 Repeat with each value you want to search

Resulting values in the example above:

```
       A:   B:                 C:      D:
 1 :   0    001011011101111    1       10
 2 :   0                       11      4
 3 :   1                       111     2
 4 :   0                       1111    1
 5 :   1    
 6 :   1    
 7 :   0    
 8 :   1    
 9 :   1    
 10:   1    
 11:   0    
 12:   1    
 13:   1    
 14:   1    
 15:   1
```